# How to use MongoDB aggregation to convert a string of key value pairs into a document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am playing around with the MongoDB aggregation pipeline trying to see if I can use it to parse a file with the following format.

```
FIELD1:ABC
FIELD2:DEF
...
FIELD12:YZ
RowData:__ __ 01 __ __
RowData:__ 02 01 01 __
RowData:__ __ 03 __ __
```

I have directly inserted the file stream into a mongo document into a field called fileStream.  Now I am trying to create a pipeline to add each field to the document.  I have been somewhat successful but I can't seem to get the keys with duplicate values into an array.

Problem I am having is that any duplicate keys get over written with the last value.

With This pipeline I get an array of arrays with element 0 being the key and element 1 being the value. So when I use $arrayToObject only the last field is retained for duplicate keys.

```
db.maps.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      'rows':
      {
        $map:
        {
          input: {
            // Sinf Rows
            $filter: {
              input: { $split: ['$fileStream', '\r\n'] },
              as: 'row',
              cond: { $ne: ['$$row', ''] }
            }
          },
          as: 'row',
          in:
            {
              $split: ['$$row', ':']
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]).pretty()
```

This pipeline is close but the RowData elements are not contained in a array.

```
db.maps.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      'rows':
      {
        $map:
        {
          input: {
            // Sinf Rows
            $filter: {
              input: { $split: ['$fileStream', '\r\n'] },
              as: 'row',
              cond: { $ne: ['$$row', ''] }
            }
          },
          as: 'row',
          in:
            {
              $cond: [{ $eq: [{ $arrayElemAt: [{ $split: ['$$row', ':'] }, 0] }, 'RowData'] }, { $arrayElemAt: [{ $split: ['$$row', ':'] }, 1] }, { $split: ['$$row', ':'] }]
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]).pretty()
```

I would like to combine any duplicate keys into the same array.

So something like this

```
"file": 
{
"FIELD1": "ABC"
...
"RowData": 
[
"__ __ 01 __ __",
"__ 02 01 01 __",
"__ __ 03 __ __"
]
}
```

I am able to do this in js using reduce but how can I accumulate into an array or object using the aggregation $reduce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.maps.aggregate([
    {
        $project:{
            "file":{
                $reduce:{
                    "input":{
                        $split:["$fileStream","\n"]
                    },
                    "initialValue":{
                        "elements":[]
                    },
                    "in":{
                        "elements":{
                            $concatArrays:[
                                "$$value.elements",
                                [
                                    {
                                        $let:{
                                            "vars":{
                                                "splitted":{
                                                    $split:["$$this",":"]
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "in":{
                                                "k":{
                                                    $arrayElemAt:["$$splitted",0]
                                                },
                                                "v":{
                                                    $arrayElemAt:["$$splitted",1]
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind:"$file.elements"
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":{
                "_id":"$_id",
                "element":"$file.elements.k"
            },
            "k":{
                $first:"$file.elements.k"
            },
            "v":{
                $push:"$file.elements.v"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields:{
            "v":{
                $cond:[
                    {
                        $gt:[
                            {
                                $size:"$v"
                            },
                            1
                        ]
                    },
                    "$v",
                    {
                        $arrayElemAt:["$v",0]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":"$_id._id",
            "file":{
                $push:{
                    "k":"$k",
                    "v":"$v"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "file":{
                $arrayToObject:"$file"
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d73c530f04b490307453cfe"),
    "fileStream" : "FIELD1:ABC\nFIELD2:DEF\nRowData:__ __ 01 __ __\nRowData:__ 02 01 01 __\nRowData:__ __ 03 __ __"
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d73c530f04b490307453cfe"),
    "file" : {
        "RowData" : [
            "__ __ 01 __ __",
            "__ 02 01 01 __",
            "__ __ 03 __ __"
        ],
        "FIELD2" : "DEF",
        "FIELD1" : "ABC"
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

- Converting file stream into an array of elements. Each element hold one key-value pair
- Grouping on the key and pushing all values for the key into an array
- Replacing the values array with the first value of array if the size is only 1. This is done because the value should not be shown as an array if its single
- Merging all key-value pairs into an array
- Converting the array of key-value pairs into an object

Comment: Wow Thanks!  It took me a while to work through the pipeline but the first group stage is really important. I added a filter to the reduce input to eliminate any blank rows in the file
`           
$filter: {
  input: { $split: ['$fileStream', '\r\n'] },
  as: 'row',
  cond: { $ne: ['$$row', ''] }
}`